# missing 1 required positional argumentエラーが直せない

Tags: python, python3

お世話になります。遺伝的アルゴリズムで巡回セールスマン問題を解くプログラムを作っています。タイトルのようなエラーに対処できません。以下、コード全体とエラー文になります。

```py
import math
import csv
import copy
import random


def read_tspfile():
    """
    tspファイルを読み込み、都市の座標(float型)を
    [[都市番号,X,Y],[...],...] の形で返す
    """
    def str2float(cities):
        data = [[0]]*len(cities)
        for i in range(len(cities)):
            city = [0]*len(cities[i])
            data[i] = city
            try:
                for j in range(len(cities[i])):
                    data[i][j] = float(cities[i][j])
            except:
                data[i]*=0
                continue
        data2 = list(filter(None,data))
        return data2

    def remove_blank(cities):
        for i in range(len(cities)):
            for j in range(len(cities[i])):
                try:
                    cities[i].remove('')
                except:
                    continue
    
    with open("a280.tsp","r") as fin:
        data = [city.split(' ') for city in fin.read().splitlines()]
        remove_blank(data)
        cities_data = str2float(data)
    return cities_data



cities_data = read_tspfile()
population = []  # [[経路],[経路],[経路]...[経路]]
cities = []  # Cityオブジェクトを入れるリスト
CITIES_N = len(cities_data)  # 都市数



class City:
    def __init__(self,num,X,Y):
        self.num = num
        self.X = X
        self.Y = Y



class Route:
    def __init__(self):
        self.distance = 0
        
        #　経路を作成(重複なしのランダム)
        self.citynums = random.sample(list(range(CITIES_N)),CITIES_N)
    
    
    def calc_distance(self):
        """ citynumsリストの各都市間の距離の総和を求める """
        self.distance = 0
        for i,num in enumerate(self.citynums):
            """ 
            1つ前の都市との距離を計算
            i=0のとき、i-1は最後の都市(最後の都市からスタートへの距離)
            """
            self.distance += math.dist((cities[num].X,
                                        cities[num].Y),
                                       (cities[self.citynums[i-1]].X,
                                        cities[self.citynums[i-1]].Y))
        return self.distance
    
    
    def copy_route(self,route):
        return copy.copy(route)  # deepcopy?
    
    
    def crossover(self, p1, p2):
        # 子の遺伝子情報
        c1 = self.copy_gene(p1)
        c2 = self.copy_gene(p2)
        for i in range(len(c1)):
            if random.random() > 0.5:
                c1[i], c2[i] = c2[i], c1[i]
                
        mutated_c1, mutated_c2 = self.mutate(c1,c2)
        
        return mutated_c1,mutated_c2
   
    
    # 一様交叉
    def mutate(self,c1,c2,mutate_rate=0.05):
        if random.random() > mutate_rate:
            if random.random() > 0.5:
                select_num = [i for i in range(c1)]
                select_index = random.sample(select_num, 2)
                
                a = c1[select_index[0]]
                b = c1[select_index[1]]
                c1[select_index[1]] = a
                c1[select_index[0]] = b

            else:
                select_num = [i for i in range(c2)]
                select_index = random.sample(select_num, 2)
                
                a = c2[select_index[0]]
                b = c2[select_index[1]]
                c2[select_index[1]] = a
                c2[select_index[0]] = b
        
        return c1,c2
    

def pfga():

    # 2未満なら追加。これだけだとランダムに2こ取り出す動作でエラー吐く。別途初期集団は作っておく
    if len(population) < 2:
        population.append(Route())

    # ランダムに2個取り出す
    p1 = population.pop(random.randint(0, len(population)-1))
    p2 = population.pop(random.randint(0, len(population)-1))

    # 子を作成
    c1, c2 = Route.crossover(p1,p2)

    if p1.calc_distance() < p2.calc_distance():
        p_min = p1
        p_max = p2
    else:
        p_min = p2
        p_max = p1
    if c1.calc_distance() < c2.calc_distance():
        c_min = c1
        c_max = c2
    else:
        c_min = c2
        c_max = c1

    if c_min.calc_distance() >= p_max.calc_distance():
        # 子2個体がともに親の2個体より良かった場合
        # 子2個体及び適応度の良かった方の親個体計3個体が局所集団に戻り、局所集団数は1増加する。
        population.append(c1)
        population.append(c2)
        population.append(p_max)
    elif p_min.calc_distance() >= c_max.calc_distsnce():
        # 子2個体がともに親の2個体より悪かった場合
        # 親2個体のうち良かった方のみが局所集団に戻り、局所集団数は1減少する。
        population.append(p_max)
    elif p_max.calc_distance() >= c_max.calc_distance() and p_min.calc_distance() <= c_max.calc_distance():
        # 親2個体のうちどちらか一方のみが子2個体より良かった場合
        # 親2個体のうち良かった方と子2個体のうち良かった方が局所集団に戻り、局所集団数は変化しない。
        population.append(c_max)
        population.append(p_max)
    elif c_max.calc_distance() >= p_max.calc_distance() and c_min.calc_distance() <= p_max.calc_distance():
        # 子2個体のうちどちらか一方のみが親2個体より良かった場合
        # 子2個体のうち良かった方のみが局所集団に戻り、全探索空間からランダムに1個体選んで局所集団に追加する。局所集団数は変化しない。
        population.append(c_max)
        population.append(Route())
    else:
        raise ValueError("not comming")
    
        


# citiesにCityオブジェクトを入れる
for i in range(CITIES_N):
    cities.append(City(cities_data[i][0],
                       cities_data[i][1],
                       cities_data[i][2]))  # num,X,Yの順


# populationに個体を追加
for i in range(2):
    population.append(Route())


generation = 0
best_route = random.choice(population)  # 個体(経路)
best_dist = best_route.calc_distance()  # 距離
first = best_dist  # 1番優秀



with open('PfGA_result.csv','w') as fout:
    
    csvout = csv.writer(fout)
    result = []
    
    while True:
        pfga()
        
        population.sort(key=Route.calc_distance)
        dist1 = population[0].calc_distance()
        
        if dist1 < best_dist:
            best_dist = dist1
            best_route = population[0]
        
        generation += 1
        
        if generation == 1 or generation%100 == 0:
            data = []
            data.extend([generation,best_dist])
            result.append(data)
            if generation == 500:
                csvout.writerows(result)
                print(best_route.citynums)
                break
```

エラー文

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File …, line 198, in <module>
    pfga()

  File ..., line 133, in pfga
    c1, c2 = Route.crossover(p1,p2)

TypeError: crossover() missing 1 required positional argument: 'p2'
```

以上になります。汚いコードで恐縮ですが、よろしければ回答お願いします。

Comment: インスタンスからメソッドにアクセスすると，暗黙的にインスタンス自身が第一引数としてメソッドに渡されます．ソースコードではクラスから直接メソッドにアクセスしているため，インスタンスが渡されず引数の数が不足しているというのがエラーの原因です．
classmethodデコレータの利用を検討してください．[組み込み関数 - classmethod](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございました。このエラーについてはクラスメソッドを用いたところ、解決できました。